# Solve $T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+2^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Solve $$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+2^{n}.$$

### My approach

\begin{align*}
T(n)&=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+2^{n}\\
&=T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{n}\\
&=T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+2^{\frac{n}{2^{2}}}+2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{n},
\end{align*}

> So $$T(n)=2^{n}+2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{\frac{n}{2^{2}}}+\cdots+1.
> $$

Assuming base case as $T(1)=1$, then

### $$T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}\right)=1\Longrightarrow \frac{n}{2^{k}}=1 \Longrightarrow k=\log_2{n}.$$

> \begin{align*}
> T(n)&=2^{n}+2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{\frac{n}{2^{2}}}+\cdots+1\\
> &=2^{n} \times \frac{(2^{\frac{n}{2}})^{k+1}-1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}-1}.
> \end{align*}

I am unable to move forward. I know I have to apply geometric progression. Please help me out.

Comment: The series you got doesn't give you a geometric progression, so the last result on $T(n)$ is wrong. You have something like $x+x^{1/2}+x^{1/4}+\dots+x^{n/n}$ instead.

Comment: The intermediate result $k=\log_2{n}$ just shows that $n$ must be of the form $2^k$ for the recurrence to make sense.

Comment: Is it a complexity question?

Comment: I have $2^{2^0}+2^{2^1}+\dots +2^{2^k}$. Not sure how to calculate the sum.